# Как (и можно ли) узнать количество байт, выделенных функции / C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Имеем следующий код на C++:

```
void func() { ... }

void (*funcPtr)() = func;
std::cout << sizeof(funcPtr);
```

В консоль будет выведено либо число 4 либо число 8 (в зависимости от архитектуры)
Но... Я хочу узнать сколько байт занимает функция в памяти (включая все инструкции, которые она выполняет), а **не** сколько байт занимает хранение указателя на нее.

Comment: Есть вариант вычислить размер функции, отнимая адрес от другой функции ниже. Но это не стандартно, могут функции оказаться не рядом. Не вычисляет места для хранения статических переменных функции, константных строк, используемых в ней. Лучше скажите конкретную цель: для чего? И размер статических переменных нужно или нет?

Comment: @AlexGlebe предложил очень неплохой вариант, котрый мне тоже приходил в голову. Но меня остановило вот что: в общем случае, надо перебрать все функции в программе и тогда можно составить "карту памяти". Но как их перебрать без reflection?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, вопрос скорее из чистого любопытства, интересно узнать есть ли в языке такие возможности...

Comment: нет, в языке таких возможностей нет. Более того, компилятор иногда делает такие хитрые оптимизации, что ответ на этот вопрос стает очень скользкий ( к примеру, в некоторых случаях, если функция просто вызывает другую, то компилятор можно просто вставить jump на нужную. И получается размер функции всего то несколько байт  и в ней даже ret нет. Но задачу можно решить инструментами компилятора. Вот, к примеру, gcc так умеет - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11720340/tool-to-analyze-size-of-elf-sections-and-symbol

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight - спасибо, очень полезная ссылка!